# How to save a form inputs in database and retrieve it from database with out form submision

Tags: nodes, forms, database

hi can i store form inputs in database and retrieve it from database with validation

I search many sites but neither any documentation or example or any thing i found for  drupal7 . 
I didn't understand why it is not asked before .

I want to save a node form value in database with out form submition and at the time of retrieving i just want to validate those data .

what i achieve is now i can store data without submition or validation but when i was trying to validate those data in listing page (retrieve) page i can't do that.

i have tried node_validate() drupal_form_validate()  but neither of it works is i am doing some thing wrong

here is my code

```
function MY_MODULE_list() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('id')),
    array('data' => t('form_id')),
    array('data' => t('owner')),
    array('data' => t('invalid input')),
  );
  $rows = array();

  $result = db_select('my_table', 'lt')
    ->fields('lt', array('id', 'form_id', 'owner', 'form_state', 'form_state_storage', 'form_state_input', 'form_state_node'))
    ->range(0,30)
    ->execute();

  if (!$result) {
    $rows[] = array(array('data' => t('No Result found.'), 'colspan' => 10));
  }
  else {
    $node_form = new stdClass;
    $node_form->type = 'node_type';
    $node_form->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $form = drupal_get_form('node_type_node_form',$node_form);
    $form['#token'] = FALSE;
    foreach($result as $r){
        $form_state = @unserialize($r->form_state);
        $form_state_node = @unserialize($r->form_state_node);
        $form_state_input = @unserialize($r->form_state_input);
        $form_state_input['form_token'] = FALSE;
        $form_state_input['form_build_id'] = FALSE;
        $form_state['node'] = $form_state_node;
        $form_state['input'] = $form_state_input;
        unset($form['form_token']);
        unset($form['#token']);
        unset($form_state['form_token']);

        node_validate($form_state_node,$form,$form_state);

        $errors = form_get_errors();
        $noOfError = 'empty';
        if (!empty($errors)) {
          $noOfError = count($errors);
        } 
        form_clear_error();


      $rows[] = array(
                    array('data' => $r->lid),
                    array('data' => $r->form_id),
                    array('data' => l(t(user_load($r->owner)->name), '/user/'.$r->owner)),
                    array('data' => $noOfError),
                  );
    }
  }

  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'MY_MODULE'),
  );
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to save the form values without creating a node?  Seems counter-productive...

Comment: use ajax see form api

Comment: hey thanks for reply i want to help the end user for helping the field error. means in which field they put the wrong information

Comment: did you read my code @harsh i already saved the problem  is with validation at a listing page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,
create a own table for storing formstate and retrive it on my module page .
at that time drupal_validate_form does the magic.